# views count calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

could you give me idea how to calculate unique views of page? If i will increase counter on each page load it will be no good, otherside storing information of viewed pages in session looks like not ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to increase the counter on every single hit, but only on the first time some user visists, you must store it somewhere. I would store it in a database table and store the session_id and the page in this table. Then I would increase the counter only if the current session haven't already visited the current page and then store it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

**use & search for the GOOGLE ANALYTICS.**

Comment: unacceptable - i'd like to use simple counter instead integration with analytics to fetch views count for page

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but what about [is_visitable](https://github.com/grimen/is_visitable)?

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar things using a before filter and a `page_views` table.

Here's a migration to create the table:

```
class PageViews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :page_views do |t|
      t.string :controller
      t.string :action
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And a model class: `/app/models/page_view.rb`:

```
class PageView < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :action, :controller
end
```

Then in the application_controller add a `before_filter` to insert a record with every request:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :track_page_request
  def track_page_request
    PageView.create({:controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action]})
  end
end
```